# Records in NSMutableArray not sorted

Tags: cocoa, sorting, core-data, nstableview

I am using a `NSArrayController` to display the records in a `NSTableView`. I am reading back a selected record using `[recordArray objectAtIndex:[tableView selectedRow]]`. This is working fine when I don't click any of the headers in the table to sort the data. When I click a header to sort the data, the data is sorted on the screen but not in my recordArray and the order of my recordArray does not match the order of the data in the table view anymore.

My recordArray is of type `NSMutableArray` and contains records of type BrowserRecord. BrowserRecord contains the fields name and type (both `NSString` and readwrite).

I've followed all the guidelines and examples found in books and on the internet and I find it very confusing that it doesn't work for me (my previous version of the code without core-data was working fine). I must be doing something very strange. Hope that someone can point me out into the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array controller is managing the sorted contents. Ask it for its `-arrangedObjects.`